# How do I rearrange specific characters in a string using regexp in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, gsub

How do I rearrange the characters in '3 4 +' to '3 + 4' using regexp? I've written the following:

```
puts ('3 4 +').gsub(/\d \d \W/, '\1 \3 \2')
```

But nothing is being printed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the sub group by `()`.

```
'3 4 +'.gsub /(\d+) (\d+) (\W)/, '\1 \3 \2'
```